# Purpose of ArrayRef

Tags: c++, arrays, llvm, pass-by-reference

I stumbled upon this http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ArrayRef.html and I am trying to understand what it is supposed to be for.

I cant see what problem `ArrayRef` solves, could someone please explain the motivation behind this?

Comment: It serves as base class for all those different types of array references. The problem it solves is seemingly to handle all the derived classes uniformly in an AST.

Comment: I don't think I follow ... can you not just template an argument and have that accept any different type of array of any length? similar to what std::array does?

Comment: It's used to _represent_ such arrays in a syntax representation as far I've understood.

Comment: This class does not own the underlying data. When you chop it in parts, you don't chop underlying data - that's the purpose. You can use C-style T* or T[] and size in parameters instead... and work without iterators and aux methods, but passing ArrayRef by value and by reference is convenient and doesn't cost much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the same idea behind `std::string_view` : to provide a general view to something, without managing it's lifetime.

In the case of `ArrayRef` (which is a terrible name, ArrayView is much better IMHO), it can view other arrays type, including the non-object builtin array (C array). so for example , your function can look like this:

```
size_t sum (ArrayRef<size_t> view){
   return std::accumulate(view.begin(),view.end(),0);
}
```

and call it with a C-Array:

```
size_t arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
auto _sum = sum(arr);
```

if you change the argument type to, for example, `std::vector`, `ArrayRef` still works.

> can you not just template an argument and have that accept any
>   different type of array of any length?

the point is that you don't have to point to the first element, you can point to the 2 ,3 or any element inside the array, so basically your suggested function will look like

```
template<class Array>
void doSomthing(Array& array , size_t pos, size_t length){/*...*/}
```

you'de much better with a class in this case (just like you'de better with `std::string_view` rather than `const char*` + `size_t`).

Comment: What I meant by templating the parameter was to template it such that it could capture the size information with it, for example `T (&arr) [N]` or something like that.  This makes sense though, I did not know that it was meant for all different "array-like" types as well